# Creating workitem in Azure DevOps using REST API - Status 404 not found

Tags: c#, rest, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have been trying to create work items in Azure DevOps.
But got an error of "404 not found"

ItemType is -Task with $ in prefix.
When I try to get the specific work item number in the url (get request) I get other items, so I know for sure that the org + project and the rest of the URI is correct.

What could be the issue? (I gave full access permissions as well when generated the token (PAT))

```
    using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace TaskCreator
{
    static class Azure
    {
        public const string BASE = "https://dev.azure.com";
        public const string PAT = "XXX";
        public const string ORG = "Org2";
        public const string API = "api-version=6.0";
        public const string PROJECT = "Project2";
        public const string WIT_TYPE = "$Task";
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create and initialize HttpClient instance.
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Set Media Type of Response.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // Generate base64 encoded authorization header.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", Azure.PAT))));

            // Build the URI for creating Work Item.
            string uri = String.Join("?", String.Join("/", Azure.BASE, Azure.ORG, Azure.PROJECT, "_apis/wit/workitems", Azure.WIT_TYPE), Azure.API);

            // Create Request body in JSON format.
            string json = "[{ \"op\": \"add\", \"path\": \"/fields/System.Title\", \"from\": null, \"value\": \"REST API Demo task\"}]";
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

            // Call CreateWIT method.
            string result = CreateWIT(client, uri, content).Result;

            // Pretty print the JSON if result not empty or null.
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                dynamic wit = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(result);
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wit, Formatting.Indented));
            }

            // Presss any key to exit
            Console.ReadLine();
            client.Dispose();
        }

        public static async Task<string> CreateWIT(HttpClient client, string uri, HttpContent content)
        {
            try
            {
                // Send asynchronous POST request.
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return (await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return string.Empty;
            }
        } // End of CreateWIT method
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the value of `url` variable

Comment: URI - https://dev.azure.com/Org2/Project2/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=6.0"

Comment: Are you sure that it should be POST request? I think it should be GET

Comment: @EilonA I was able to run your code without any errors and saw the work item got created. Not sure what the exact issue could be. Have you tried it with a different organization, or a different PAT? Does your account have enough [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops) to create a work item?

Comment: @viveknuna Nope, the [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API is a POST call.

Answer (score 0):

From UI, you can check whether you are able to create task work item.  I encountered a similar behavior when the Task workitem was greyed out at the UI level.

Also, check the code with other workitem types. (for instance bug)